# Select Data by check box click next and unselect the selected row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a crf form for my university project .
i created course table i select some data from course but where student click the completed course and next click .then next page show same data base table but not those courses, student already selected.and 
then student can subset for applied courses.
But when i select some course and click next, But it show the previous row in course table. but i want selected course row not select when i click . cause completed course not want to select for applying course.

1. I want to select some row from a database when aply it show the same databases all row except the selected row

i add the same line in the problem line..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
        <title>
         CRF Form
         </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/admin_style.css" >
   </head>  
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <a href="index.php">
        <h1>
            Welcome to the CRF Form
        </h1>
    </a>
    </div>
    <form action="selection.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div id="">
        <table width="1000" border="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" align="center" bgcolor="yellow">
            <h1>
            Slect your completed course
            </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="orange">
            <th>
                selection:
            </th>
            <th>
                Course id:
            </th>
            <th>
                Course title:
            </th>
            <th>
                Course credits:
            </th>
            <th>
                Course statust:
            </th>
            <th>
                Delete Post:
            </th>
            <th>
                Edit Post:
            </th>

        </tr>

    <?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");

    $query="select * from course";

    $run=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $course_id=$row['course_id'];
    $course_title=$row['course_title'];
    $course_credits=$row['course_credits'];
    $course_status=$row['course_status'];

    ?>


        <tr align="center" bgcolor="pink">
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="complete[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $course_id; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $course_title; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $course_credits; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $course_status; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $post_id ?>">
            Delete
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="Edit.php?edit=<?php echo $post_id ?>">
            Edit
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <?php } ?>


        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="7">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="NEXT">
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the selec.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    CRF Form
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/admin_style.css" >
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <a href="index.php">
        <h1>
            Welcome to the CRF Form
        </h1>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="">
        <table width="1000" border="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" align="center" bgcolor="yellow">
            <h1>
            Slect your completed course
            </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="orange">
            <th>selection:</th>
            <th>Course id:</th>
            <th>Course title:</th>
            <th>Course credits:</th>
            <th>Course statust:</th>
            <th>Delete Post:</th>
            <th>Edit Post:</th>

        </tr>

    <?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");

    $check=$_POST['complete'];
    foreach($check as $ch){
    $select= " id!='".$ch."' and ";//here is the problem
    }


    $query="select * from course
    where $select id!='0'";

    $run=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $course_id=$row['course_id'];
    $course_title=$row['course_title'];
    $course_credits=$row['course_credits'];
    $course_status=$row['course_status'];

    ?>


        <tr align="center" bgcolor="pink">
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="completed" /></input>

            </td>
            <td><?php echo $course_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $course_title; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $course_credits; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $course_status; ?></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $post_id ?>">Delete</a></td>
            <td><a href="Edit.php?edit=<?php echo $post_id ?>">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php  } ?>



        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question please ?

Comment: I want to select some row from a database when aply it show the same databases all row except the selected row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're saying the once the course is selected it shouldn't be displayed on the next page where the student can have a look on the other courses?

If is so then you can use following sql query on the next page where you don't want to display the student's completed course.

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE id != $course_id
```

Let me know if I'm wrong. I didn't comment out as my reputations were low and stackoverflow didn't allow me to.

**[EDITED]**

This is your complete code.

> Your select php file:

```
//assuming that you are logging in the students with their username or email id, if so then store their username in a session where logging in.
<?php 
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    include("includes/connect.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $course_id= $_POST['course_id'];
    $course_title= $_POST['course_title'];
    $course_credits= $_POST['course_credits'];
    $course_status= $_POST['course_status'];

    $query="SELECT course.id,course.title,course.credits,course.status FROM course WHERE course.username = $user";

    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
    $course_id= $_SESSION['course_id'] = $row['course_id'];
    $course_title=$row['course_title'];
    $course_credits=$row['course_credits'];
    $course_status=$row['course_status'];
}
    ?>
```

> Now in your next php file :

```
$already_selected_course = $_SESSION['course_id'];

Now the query should look like.

$query = "SELECT course.id,course.title,course.credits,course.status FROM course WHERE course.id != $already_selected_course";
```

This is it. Note: This solution might contain some errors of brackets etc but the logic is clear.

**For better knowledge have a look at my [MySQL Complete Video Series](http://www.uolbscs.com/my_courses/mysql_database_complete_video_course.php) here!**

Comment: when i use foreach($check as $ch){ $select= " id!='".$ch."' and ";//here is the problem } it not work but if i use foreach{......... last <?php } }?> it repeat more row... Please tell   how i ignore selected row in the table

Comment: help me for give me advice ..
when i select row i can view the selected row from the table..
is there any way to show the un selected row.
(i select data from check box)

Comment: Explain more question a bit more!