# Show unchecked data in php

Tags: php

I want to show cheeked data .. This program show only selected data
so please help me  to solve this problem.

```
   <form method="post" action="" id="frm_id">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="10,Anu" />Anu
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="11,Raj" />Raj
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="12,Ram" />Ram
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="13,xxx" />xxx
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="14,yyy" />yyyy
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="15,zzz" />zzz
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="16,qqqq" />qqqq
    <input type="submit" value="Insert"  name="sub"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
    $id=$_POST['chkid'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
    {
    $exp=explode(',',$id[$i]);//Explode id and name
    echo 'id='.$exp[0].',Name='.$exp[1];echo "<br>";
    echo $query="INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('$exp[0]','$exp[1]')";echo "<br><br>";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

if is select zzz and qqqq
the result is show

```
id=15,Name=zzz
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('15','zzz')

id=16,Name=qqqq
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('16','qqqq')
```

but i want when i select zzz and qqqq result show me:

```
id=10,Name=Anu
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('10','Anu')

id=11,Name=Raj
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('11','Raj')

id=12,Name=Ram
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('12','Ram')

id=13,Name=xxx
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('13','xxx')

id=14,Name=yyy
INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('14','yyy')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since unchecked items aren't posted, you could devise a way in order to get those. One way is to create a mapping of those input checkboxes first. From there, you'll need to get the input and compare them to the map.

Its easier to map those using an array:

```
$map = array(
    10 => 'Anu',
    11 => "Raj" ,
    12 => "Ram" ,
    13 => "xxx" ,
    14 => "yyy" ,
    15 => "zzz" ,
    16 => "qqqq",
);
```

From there process the input accordingly and use `array_diff_key`. So that in turn you'll get the unchecked ones:

```
<?php

$map = array(
    10 => 'Anu',
    11 => "Raj" ,
    12 => "Ram" ,
    13 => "xxx" ,
    14 => "yyy" ,
    15 => "zzz" ,
    16 => "qqqq",
);

?>

<form method="post" action="" id="frm_id">
    <?php foreach($map as $id => $val): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkid[]" value="<?php echo "$id,$val"; ?>" /><?php echo $val; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert"  name="sub"/>
</form>
<?php



if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $ids = $_POST['chkid'];
    $input = array();
    foreach($ids as $value) {
        list($id, $val) = explode(',', $value);
        $input[$id] = $val;
    }

    $exps = array_diff_key($map, $input);

    foreach($exps as $id => $exp) {
        echo $query="INSERT INTO tbl_student (id,name) values ('$id','$exp')";echo "<br><br>";
    }

}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nKj2QQ)

Though is code is unsafe and open to SQL injections as you are directly introducing user input into query statement, you can use prepared statements to make safer queries. This is by way of PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE NAME', 'username', 'password');
$query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_student (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($exps as $id => $exp) {
    $stmt->execute(array($id, $exp));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260467/select-data-by-check-box-click-next-and-unselect-the-selected-row

please go there and give a solution this is question is create for that question... Please go there

Comment: Thanks for your help its work ...!!!
are you tell me how i vote your answer i am new here ... i don't know how i vote ,, when i click it usefull but it say Vote Up requires 15 reputation..
and please go there and solv this problem too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260467/select-data-by-check-box-click-next-and-unselect-the-selected-row

Comment: @Al-mahbubKhan you can upvote now, and if you like this answer you can mark it as resolved by clicking the checkmark on the left, glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

You never get unchecked checkboxes to be sent to the server. In this case try using prefilled arrays.

```
$listOfStudents = array( 10 => "anu", 11 => "Raj" .... );
```

change your form inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkid[10]" value="Anu" />Anu
```

Then after form Submit you can compare:

```
$result=array_diff_key($listOfStudents, $chkid);
print_r($result);
```

This should help you. The result will get you the students which are not submitted in the form....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260467/select-data-by-check-box-click-next-and-unselect-the-selected-row

please go there and give a solution this is question is create for that question... Please go there